# Imagemagick/Graphicsmagick commands in fluid image viewhelper?

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-7.x

Is it possible to get `f:image` or `v:media.image` or a similar available viewhelper to perform some classic TYPO3 imagemagick stunts, like converting an image to grayscale?

Like

```
10 = IMAGE
10.file.params = -type Grayscale
```

Or would I have to extend `f:image` with an own VH?

And If I'd have to do that: I guess it would be the right approach to just pass on these params to IM/GM, right? Where would I have to look to see how that's correctly done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this closed issue https://forge.typo3.org/issues/41347,
this feature has existing patch, but was abandoned (see Christian Kuhn comment why -> https://review.typo3.org/#/c/21162/), so now you need an own VH.

**Edit:**

If you want to have special effects on images you can use CSS property today, just use simple CSS Filters, with pretty nice browsers support today http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters

Examples:

- http://www.cssreflex.com/css-generators/filter/
- https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/filter/

Comment: Not in all cases, css filters are sufficient: think about your client's "gray scale" image suddenly turning up in its original colors on google image

Comment: the argument for rejecting the patch seems largely to be based on "imagemagick sucks" as a point of departure. which may be true, but then these params should also be removed from TS. But I don't want to rant, it's ok & probably for the best. So instead of using f:image, I could just generate the IMAGE as a cObj in TS and insert it into the fluid template with f:cObj, right? That's perfectly feasible! Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

I use TypoScript to configure images and call them in fluid:

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.fluidResponsiveImages" data="{image.uid}"></f:cObject>
```

TypoScript example:

```
#
# TypoScript Setup: lib.fluidResponsiveImages
# Load after tt_content.t3s
#
lib.fluidResponsiveImages = IMAGE
lib.fluidResponsiveImages  {
    file {
        import.current = 1
        treatIdAsReference = 1
        width = 932
    }
    sourceCollection < tt_content.image.20.1.sourceCollection
    layoutKey < tt_content.image.20.1.layoutKey
    layout < tt_content.image.20.1.layout
    params < tt_content.image.20.1.params
}
```

Comment: Could you post an example of the TS, how does it receive the image uid?

Comment: I extend my answer with TypoScript example.

Comment: ah, nice, so current gets the value from f:cObject, thanks